# LibreOffice Calc prompting to update "links to other files". Why?

Tags: ubuntu, libreoffice-calc

I have a spread sheet that recently started asking "This file contains links to other files, should they be updated". I have been using this file for a while and don't know why it started, what it means, or how to stop it.  Any suggestions?

LibreOffice 3.4.4
OOO340m1 (Build:402)
Running on Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: Have you ever copied content over from another document? The content may have been linked instead of embedded.

Comment: Possibly, it is in a group of files that I sometimes do, can you explain a little and put it in an answer?

Comment: @iglvzx, please try http://superuser.com/questions/418079/why-does-libreoffice-calc-ask-about-updating-links-in-excel-2007-xls-file-when/436699#436699 woraround. However, it doesn't work for me :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the choice to **embed** or **link** to an object when you **insert** content into your document from another source. **Paste Special** also gives you a choice to link objects from the clipboard.

[image: paste special]

Each method has it's own benefits. With embedding, all the content is contained within a single file. This simplifies distributing documents or moving them around, as all the content moves together. On the other hand, linking reduces redundancy, by having a single source for an object. A link's path can be relative or absolute.

Since you are receiving a message about linked objects in your file, the **Edit** > **Links** command will highlight them for you. You can then remove the links and the objects will instead be embedded.

[image: edit links]

### Example:

[image: source]

[image: link]

---

### Update:

I am having issues with **Break Link** in LibreOffice 3.4.5. It should be removing the links and embedding the latest contents, but the link persists after saving and closing.

Comment: Ok, the last time it happened (right before I posted the question) I hit the yes (update) button. Previously I had always said no because I wasn't sure what was up. Now it isn't asking me anymore and the Edit>Links doesn't show anything.  So I obviously ruined my chances of being certain, but this is good info that I didn't know before so I'm going to accept it.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the Edit -> Links suggestion, unfortunately I have a workbook where I get the same prompt as the OP but Edit -> Links is grayed out.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this can happen because of pasting a formula from another sheet that references something not in the current sheet (giving a #REF! error), then deleting it again.

It can be easily fixed by going into Insert > Names > Manage and deleting the problem named reference.  (Shortcut: Ctrl+F3).

Credit to [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/418079/why-does-libreoffice-calc-ask-about-updating-links-in-excel-2007-xls-file-when), but I note someone had asked here as well.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It worked for me: after I found a #REF! cell and deleted its content, I saved the spreadsheet file, closed LibreOffice Calc and opened the spreadsheet file again. The issue doesn't happen anymore. Thanks again.